# Yii2 - validating ISO8601 datetime format with DateValidator

Tags: php, datetime, yii2

I have a ISO8601 datetime value in the following format (generated by JS):

```
var d = new Date(),
    dateString = d.toISOString(); // returns "2017-08-17T07:39:34.502Z"
```

In my model, I want to create a validation rule to validate this value.

I have tried the following format, but it is reporting that the datetime string is invalid:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        ['endTime', 'datetime', 'format' => 'php:DateTime::ATOM'],
        ...
    ];
}
```

I used `DateTime::ATOM` instead of `DateTime::ISO8601` because that's what the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601) itself recommends.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
['endTime', 'date', 'format' => 'php:' . \DateTime::ATOM],
```

Edit: `datetime` was wrong - proper validator is `date`

Comment: Sadly, this did not work for me, the javascript `toISOString()` function returns `2022-11-07T15:10:00.000Z ` so i used `'format' => 'php:Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z'` which works.